# why are votes for deleted question/answer not shown in reputation tab

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I got a downvote on a question which was shortly afterwards closed/deletd, but now it doesn't show on my reputation history tab.

Why is that?

Comment: Because the question was deleted.  Eventually, your reputation will be recalc'ed, and the downvotes your received will be removed from your reputation score.

Comment: ah, i thought the downvotes were "upheld". it makes sense now, thanks

Comment: go to stackoverflow.com/reputation and scroll to the bottom. Hit the reclac button. All will be well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Your question was deleted.

Note the notice at the bottom of [your reputation page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/62951/antony-scott?tab=reputation):

[image: Notice on bottom of reputation page]

That said, you can *force* a recalc of your reputation by going to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation) and click on the button at the bottom:

[image]